# Disparity between Javascript engines in Java

Tags: javascript, java

So currently I have a Java crawler that needs to calculate a value using a Javascript engine. I tried two different engines, one is **javax.script.ScriptEngine**, and another is **com.eclipsesource.v8.V8** engine. Somehow they have different ways of handling precision:

```
l = 1.920337417298865e+77
var n = new Number(l.toPrecision(15));
```

The first engine gives me n = 1.92033741729887e+77 (round up), the second up gives me 1.92033741729886e+77 (round down). The second value is the one that I expected, but using **com.eclipsesource.v8.V8** is troublesome, because I couldn't create two JVMs to use V8 engine in Windows (https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/issues/39). What is a good way to use **javax.script.ScriptEngine** to achieve the same value?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it is just easy to do substring to do a rounddown:

```
var n = l.toPrecision(16);

n = (n.toString().substring(0, 16) + n.toString().substring(17, n.toString().length))
```